# "This operation is not supported" when trying to call XLWorkbook SaveAs( ) to a MemoryStream

Tags: c#, closedxml

I have an endpoint that i expect to receive a zip with some files(spreadsheet and images). I have to read the data that are in the spreadsheet, and if i find some inconsistency, i should highlight the corresponding cells of the spreasheet and return this changed spreadsheet.

I am using the ZipFile class to handle the received zip, and i am also using the XLWorkbook (ClosedXLM lib) to handle the spreadsheet. However, when i try to save the changes made yo the spreadsheet in a MemoryStream, an exception is thrown with the message "This operation is not supported".

The first four lines of the StackTrace:

```
System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.set_Position(Int64 value)
ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.SaveAs(Stream stream, SaveOptions options)
ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.SaveAs(Stream stream, Boolean validate, Boolean evaluateFormulae)
ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.SaveAs(Stream stream)...
```

The code where i try to save the changes:

```
    private byte[] ConvertToByteArray(XLWorkbook workbook)
    {
        using MemoryStream changedSpreadsheetStream = new MemoryStream();

        workbook.SaveAs(changedSpreadsheetStream);

        return changedSpreadsheetStream.ToArray();
    }
```

I've figured out that this problem can be from the ZipFile class, because when i create (and modify) a XLWorkbook and save it, it works very well. But the problem is when i try to modify a XLWorkbook created by a ZipFile stream.

```
    private XLWorkbook OpenWorkbook(ZipArchiveEntry spreadsheet)
    {
        using var spreadsheetStream = spreadsheet.Open();

        return new XLWorkbook(spreadsheetStream);
    }
```

Comment: Looking at [XLWorkbook's code](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/blob/9ffa6559b4b375a9d49790d5d72a93a52ae2c3b1/ClosedXML/Excel/XLWorkbook.cs#L544), it keeps around a reference to the original stream, and saving will try to seek that stream before copying to the target stream. So the original stream must be seekable. This also implies that an `XLWorkbook` created from a stream just wraps the stream and modifies it, so you probably shouldn't create directly from the zip entry.